# JRE version with jib (Docker)

Tags: java, docker, jib

I'm trying to get my head around building Docker images with Google's [Jib project](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib) and [Jib Maven Plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin).

I don't understand how to specify the JRE version.

I understand I can customize in the [plugin's config](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#from-object), something like:

```
<configuration>
  <from>
    <image>gcr.io/distroless/java</image>
  </from>
</configuration>
```

but what does that mean in terms of the actual JRE version which will be used ?  What if I want say specifically JRE 8u172 ?

The Jib project states this as a feature:

> **Reproducible** - Rebuilding your container image with the same contents
>   always generates the same image.

therefore I'm assuming there must be some way to lock down the JRE version?

Level: Advanced on Java and Maven, newbie on everything Docker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Availability of 8u172 depends on whether the distributor has created a build image of that version.

java building version is not managed with docker image tags with `gcr.io/distroless/java`.
Currently `gcr.io/distroless/java:8`, it was 8u212 as below.

https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/distroless/GLOBAL/java?gcrImageListsize=30

```
~ $ docker run -it --rm  --entrypoint java  gcr.io/distroless/java:8 -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b01-1~deb9u1-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b01, mixed mode)
~ $
```

If you want to specify to java build version, I suggest using AdroptOpenJDK.

e.g.

```
<configuration>
  <from>
    <image>adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jdk8u172-b11</image>
  </from>
</configuration>
```

If you can use 8u171, you can select openjdk.

```
<configuration>
  <from>
    <image>openjdk:8u171-jre</image>
  </from>
</configuration>
```

- https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk8/tags
- https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=tags&page=4

Comment: Very good answer. I've arrived at the same conclusion: since Google's "distroless" docker images do not contain sufficient version tags there's no way to do reproducable builds. So not a deficiency in **Jib** as such except that this project advocates use of Google's distroless docker images.

Comment: Ahh. I'm not the first one to notice this. There are several [Github issues](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/issues/) on the matter. I found this sentence "Since Docker tags aren't immutable they aren't really suitable to pin to a specific version. If you want reproducibility, you really need to reference the SHA1 as the distroless base image updates fairly often, which cascades through the other images." [here](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/issues/214#issuecomment-466139615).

Comment: I see.I checked https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/1360. 
distroless does not provide a build version of 8u172. The 8u171 version was in the repository.
gcr.io/distroless/java@sha256: 8d00c1a8067379ec6876d881ec03f516d5a63ae2335c9a4e53b930f2a93c04b4

Comment: If you want  to always completly same image , it is better to use an image by  your  managed  private repository.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a base image with java preinstalled. every docker image contains tag(s), which are like versions. if you don't specify tag like you did above, then the latest is taken and that can lead to unexpected change of java version.

For example you can use `opendjk` image with java version `8u212` by using `openjdk:8u212-jre-stretch`. and in [OpenJDK Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=tags) you can see the list of all available tags